# SAP Commerce Cloud - Attribute values inheritance from Product to Variant Product

Tags: product, sap-commerce-cloud, commerce

we are using SAP Commerce Cloud 2011 and we need to know (if there is a possibility) how inheriting a Product attribute value within its Variant Product Master Data.

Our case is the following one:
we have a T-shirt (Product) that has the attribute "colour" with value "black".
Within Master Data of Product, into variants section, we have created a Variant Product which should have two attributes, "colour" (that is that one of its supertype product, so the T-shirt) and "size".

At the moment it doesn't work, so we are looking for a solution that permits us to automatically inherit the colour value of product (value is "black") on its variant, after its saving.

Is there a way to fix that?

Thanks for your attention.
Best regards,
Anthony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interceptors can solve your issue (either `Init` or `Prepare`, depending on your needs), you can get the value of the attribute from the `baseProduct` before saving the `variant`,

Related documentaion for interceptors : https://help.sap.com/viewer/d0224eca81e249cb821f2cdf45a82ace/1905/en-US/8bfbf43e8669101480d0f060d79b1baa.html